# How do you use Image.SCALE_DEFAULT correctly?

Tags: java, swing

Ive been trying to scale a image with these lines:

```
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\Album\\cover.jpg");
    Image scaleImage = ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(28, 28,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Album cover", scaleImage, JLabel.CENTER);
    jfrm.add(label);
```

I've read multiple threads before asking this question and none of them seem to describe it clearly or in other words they don't give code.

First line of code makes the image variable with the directory.

Second line is my attempt of scaling it.

The rest of code is labeling.

I already know this will get flagged as a dupe but there isn't a clear answer so I'd appreciate if someone explains it in a clearer way. I'm not the sharpest tool in the shed.

**EDIT**
My problem is that it says SCALE_DEFAULT cant be resolved im trying to scale an image but when i do it errors at SCALE_DEFAULT id like fixed code and explanation of what im doing wrong.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: The problem I have is, what’s you’re question? Does the above work or not?

Comment: SCALE_DEFAULT is 1. What happens if you put a 1 instead of SCALE_DEFAULT?

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel SCALE_DEFAULT isnt a boolean? its a method

Comment: Maybe we are using different Images. The API I see is: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance(int,int,int)

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel oh my bad i failed to mention im using swing not awt